# Wordpress: Custom post type shows double content on single template

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I have a website running Hello Elementor with a child theme and custom post types.

I have three single template files for each post type
single
single-calendar
single-market

On single-calendar php item it shows content from both single-calendar and single double content on the custom post type page.
Anyone knows why and how its even possible?

Comment: share your code

Comment: Check Elementor forum, there used to be this kind issue, You can find answer there.